# remove quotes from object with square brackets

Tags: javascript, json

I have these 2 Objects with the double quotes around **start** and **end** value

```
0: {name: "0", type: "line", start: "[20.6000,37.4000]", end: "[28.2000,30.8000]", vel: 0.3, …}
1: {name: "1", type: "line", start: "[53.3000,25.0000]", end: "[52.7000,35.3000]", vel: 0.3, …}
```

and I want to have this

```
0: {name:"0", type:"line", start: [20.600,37.4000], end: [28.2000,30.8000],...}
```

how can I remove the double quotes so **start** and **end** values become Number?

**I tried:**

`0["start"].replace(/^"(.*)"$/, '$1');`=> typeof String
`0["start"].slice(1, -1);`=> typeof String
`Number(0["start"])` => this return NaN

I am doing a Ajax post call to my NodeJs Server, where the JSON gets converted to a YAML File and then sent back.

**this is the result:**

```
segments: 
- 
  name: "0"
  type: "line"
  start: "[20.6000,37.4000]"
  end: "[28.2000,30.8000]"
  vel: 0.3
  ang: 0
```

a valid yaml but I need the **start** and **end** Value as **Number**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution using [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). Does not mutate original data set.

```js
const data=[{name:"0",type:"line",start:"[20.6000,37.4000]",end:"[28.2000,30.8000]",vel:.3},{name:"1",type:"line",start:"[53.3000,25.0000]",end:"[52.7000,35.3000]",vel:.3}];

const res = data.map(({start, end,...rest})=>{
   start = JSON.parse(start), end = JSON.parse(end);
   return {...rest, start, end}; 
})

console.log(res);
```

**Regex solution:**

```js
const data=[{name:"0",type:"line",start:"[20.6000,37.4000]",end:"[28.2000,30.8000]",vel:.3},{name:"1",type:"line",start:"[53.3000,25.0000]",end:"[52.7000,35.3000]",vel:.3}];

function stringToArray(data){
  return data.match(/\d(\.?[0-9])*/g).map(Number);
}

const res = data.map(({start, end,...rest})=>{
   start = stringToArray(start);
   end   = stringToArray(end);
   return {...rest, start, end}; 
})

console.log(res);
```

Comment: can you pls help me on this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64771289/how-to-remove-quotes-from-object-response-for-particular-key-value-and-return-th?noredirect=1#comment114521985_64771289)

Comment: @worstCoder with?

Comment: i've similar issue for what you have given solution here. and this is my thread 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64771289/how-to-remove-quotes-from-object-response-for-particular-key-value-and-return-th?noredirect=1#comment114521985_64771289

Answer (score 0):

You can try using JSON.parse

loop over your file and use

```
JSON.parse(x['start']) // JSON.parse(0['start'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop - note you will lose the zeroes at the end of the decimals when converting:

```js
var arr = [{name: "0", type: "line", start: "[20.6000,37.4000]", end: "[28.2000,30.8000]", vel: 0.3},
           {name: "1", type: "line", start: "[53.3000,25.0000]", end: "[52.7000,35.3000]", vel: 0.3}]
           
arr.forEach(function(entry) {
  entry.start = JSON.parse(entry.start); 
  entry.end   = JSON.parse(entry.end);
})      
console.log(arr)
```