# how to remove quotes from object response for particular key value and return the same structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I've have structure like below from response

```
{
    "last UpdatedTime":"18:00:01 AM",
    "has PErmission":false,
    "block UsersSubFeatures":true,
    "block CurrentUserTill":"NA",
    "unlock UserOnlyForVisibility":"['departmentXYZ']"
    
}
```

Note:  **"unlockUserOnlyForVisibility":"['departmentXYZ']"** // array in as string. But want to convert like

```
{
    "last UpdatedTime":"18:00:01 AM",
    "has PErmission":false,
    "block UsersSubFeatures":true,
    "block CurrentUserTill":"NA",
    "unlock UserOnlyForVisibility":['departmentXYZ']
    
}
```

so i tried JSON.parse(), which gives me **Unexpected syntaxError: unexpected token of in JSON at position 1
[Object object ]**

so tried regex like below which successfully removes quotes. but not sure this is the proper way to handle this or not

Thanks for the help

Comment: The *right* way to do this would be to fix whatever's generating that essentially-broken `unlockUserOnlyForVisibility` value

Comment: @CertainPerformance   I know this supposed to be fix in backend. but none looking into that. so im looking for solution on front end :( unfortunately

Comment: Yeah, I was going to suggest JSON.parse again but the quotes are a single quotes.  That's source code syntax, not JSON syntax. So some stringified source code got into your JSON somehow.  That's crazy.  If nothing else, just remove the first 2 and last 2 characters of the string.  Since the syntax is not JSON, you have to define what it IS.  It really depends on the flexibility of what syntax you DO want to permit.

Comment: @Wyck if you mean like JSON.parse(JSON.parse(data)); it gives me err. if not, am sorry for understanding your idea wrongly. pls give me example

Comment: @worstCoder, exactly.  Clearly that won't work because what's inside is not JSON. `JSON.parse(data).unlockUserOnlyForVisibility.slice(2,-2)` will work in that one particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Olyno mentioned, clearly this is something that needs to be fixed backend.

That being said, you need to replace `"[`with just `[` and `]"`with `]`, then handle the single quotes of the elements seperately.

```js
const response = `{
    "last UpdatedTime":"18:00:01 AM",
    "has PErmission":false,
    "block UsersSubFeatures":true,
    "block CurrentUserTill":"NA",
    "unlock UserOnlyForVisibility":"['hello world', 'test2']"
}`

function cleanBrokenJSONObject(data) {
  return data
  .replace(/"\[([^\]]*)\]"/g, function(_, singleQuoteElements){
    const elements = singleQuoteElements.replace(/'/g, '"');
    return `[${elements}]`
  })
}


const res = cleanBrokenJSONObject(response);

console.log(JSON.parse(res));
```

*note: this will only work with an array of depth 1 and not more*

Break down of the regex: `/"\[([^\]]*)\]"/g`

1. `"\[` match string that starts with `"[`
2. `([^\]]*)` Capture all the next characters and stop when encountering `]` (this is essentially the elements of your array)
3. `\]"` match string that ends with `]"`

When we capture the elements of the list (2), we replace all the `'` with `"`.

Test cases:

```js
const list1 = `"['hello world', 'test2']"`;
const list2 = `"['','']"`
const list3 = `"['']"`
const list4 = `"[]"`

function cleanBrokenJSONObject(data) {
  return data
  .replace(/"\[([^\]]*)\]"/g, function(a,b){
    const elements = b.replace(/'/g, '"');
    return `[${elements}]`
  })
}


[list1, list2, list3, list4].forEach(list => { 
  const res = cleanBrokenJSONObject(list);
  console.log(JSON.parse(res));
});
```

Comment: how to make for more than one depth like this kind 

`const response = `{ 

associates: {
    "last UpdatedTime":"18:00:01 AM",
    "has PErmission":false,
    "block UsersSubFeatures":true,
    "block CurrentUserTill":"NA",
    "unlock UserOnlyForVisibility":"['hello world', 'test2']"
}
}`

Comment: @worstCoder that is still an array of depth 1. The object is at a depth of 2,  but that won't affect the script I wrote. It won't work if the array has a depth more than 1 for example: `"['hello world', ['depth', '2']]"`

Comment: i conveyed it wrongly. i'm completely  fine with your current solution thats why i accepted it :) . but guide me how to modify regex to get like this `"unlock UserOnlyForVisibility": "hello world"` ..here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Sathya_da/0p9wd5zq/2/)

Comment: @worstCoder you forgot the `"` around sub (i.e.: `"sub":`)

Comment: sorry for the type bro. but it gives me ! **Uncaught TypeError: data.replace is not a function**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224407/discussion-between-kemicofa-ghost-and-worstcoder).

Answer (score 1):

The right way to fix that is to fix your backend, and how you generate and manage the value. If you really want to fix it using your frontend, you need 2 steps:

- Convert singles quotes in double quotes
- Convert the given string to an object using JSON.parse

So to make these steps, you need this code:

```js
JSON.parse("['departmentXYZ']".replace(/'/g, '"')); // ["departmentXYZ"]
```